# Противоположный, обратный, противный

Tags: семантика

Зеленый и белый чай бодрят, так как ферментация при производстве этих чаёв заняла меньше времени. Чёрный, красный расслабляют по обратной (противной, противоположной) причине.

Среди приведенных вариантов больше всего подходит слово "противоположный"? Почему слова "обратный" и "противный" не подходят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Противный` хуже звучит, потому что в данном значении относится к устаревшим словам. Современное значение - крайне неприятный.

`Обратный` (наоборот) звучит не хуже, чем `противоположный`. Кому как больше нравится...